# Infowindow showing same street view for multiple markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Infowindow showing street view but multiple markers showing same street view.
Its taking last address to show street view in all markers.

Code:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "{!acc.BillingCity}"}, function(results, status) { 
            alert("{!acc.BillingCity}");
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title : 'Click Here!!!' 
        });                    


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        var pano = null;
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
        if (pano != null) {
        pano.unbind("position");
            pano.setVisible(false);
        }
        pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("content"), {
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ANDROID
                },
        enableCloseButton: false,
        addressControl: false,
        linksControl: false
        });
        pano.bindTo("position", marker);
            pano.setVisible(true);
        });

         google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
            pano.unbind("position");
            pano.setVisible(false);
            pano = null;
        });

        markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
    }else if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
        wait = true;
        setTimeout("wait = true", 2000);        
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }      
});
```

How to deal with (StreetViewPanorama) to show street view with multiple markers.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_StreetViewInInfoWindowB.html

Comment: @ geocodezip yes , i am looking this kind of infowindow with street view. But my code having issue. Now i am getting same street view with multiple infowindow. Could you provide me some kind of stuff to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't my example work (show different streetview images in each infowindow)?

Comment: yes, i need different images in streetview for multiple infowindow according to address like "{!acc.BillingCity}".@geocodezip

Comment: deleted my answer, think it is part of the solution, though. But it is is nearly impossible to solve the problem when there is code and prerequisities we dont know about.

Comment: thanks david to seeing my code. Is there any another way to solve my problem. I have seen [StreetViewPanorama](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_StreetViewInInfoWindowB.html) this demonstration and i need this type of functionality in code. @davidkonrad